# Displaying an image from a WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am developing a web application. I am using a WCF web service to create and retrieve data from an SQL Server database. The WCF function below selects the `col_Photo` column which is of type `VARBINARY(MAX)` which holds a profile picture. When I save a record and I perform a `SELECT` query on the table, the `col_Photo` contains the bytes of the uploaded photo, so I'm assuming that the data is being saved. Here is the function that retrieves the photo:

```
public byte[] GetPhoto(string account, string id)
{
    QueryBuilder builder = new QueryBuilder();
    string query = builder.SelectQuery("tbl_" + account + "_details", new List<string> { "col_Photo" }, true, "col_Id", id, false, null, null);
    byte[] photo;

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[staffConnectionString].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

    connection.Open();
    photo = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    connection.Close();

    return photo;
}
```

In this case, `QueryBuilder` is a class that builds queries for me automatically. It is working fine. In my web application, I use the following `ActionResult` to fetch the photo off the database:

```
public ActionResult DisplayPhoto(string id)
{
    ServiceClient service = new ServiceClient();
    service.Open();

    byte[] photo = service.GetPhoto(Session[sessionManager.sessionId].ToString(), id);

    if (photo != null)
    {
        service.Close();

        return File(photo, "image/png");
    }

    else
    {
        service.Close();

        return null;
    }
}
```

In my Razor view, I use the following HTML to display the image:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DisplayPhoto", "Staff", new { id = member.Id })" class="img-thumbnail" />
```

When I run the web application, something is returned but the image isn't displayed. When I select **View Image** in the browser, I get the following error:

> The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

After debugging the web application and placing a Watch on the `photo` variable, it isn't `null` and does contain the bytes retrieved from the database. I have tried returning a `base64` URL instead but that also doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong here? Any suggestions?

Comment: change your return type to `FileContentResult ` from `ActionResult` and `return FileContentResult(photo,"image/png")`

Comment: I can change the return type `FileContentResult` but I cannot use `return FileContentResult()`. Visual Studio tells me that I cannot use a non-invocable member as a method

Comment: ohh that was my mistake use this `return new FileContentResult(photo, "image/png")`

Comment: Still the same error :(

Comment: seems like you have problem at this line while you're converting to bytes `photo = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
` i have doubt what it returns `command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()`?

Comment: might be you are just converting file name to byte array instead do something like this to convert image to byte array it's working for me `string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Img/1.png");
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filepath);
            long imageFileLength = fileInfo.Length;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            photo = br.ReadBytes((int)imageFileLength);`

Comment: If I have to use `Server.MapPath()` for a virtual directory, how do I actually put the images into that directory?